# Standard and portable way to send email from console?

Tags: command-line, email, standard, portability, mail-command

What is the most portable or standard way to send an email from the console or a script on Linux, and possibly Unix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you can use the [`mailx`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/mailx.html) command. Below is an usage example:

```
mailx -v -s "Subject" -S smtp-use-starttls -S ssl-verify=ignore -S smtp-auth=login -S smtp=smtp://<server_name>:25 -S from="email@domain.com" -S smtp-auth-user=<username> \
-S smtp-auth-password=<password> email@domain.com
```

This example is using SSL and SMTP authentication.

Answer (score 1):

If you want portability as in standard, use [`mailx`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/mailx.html). The `mail` and `Mail` commands are common but not standard and can have very different options across unix systems (including across installations of the same Linux distribution). Only a few options to `mailx` are standardized; for example, if you want custom headers, you're out of luck.

Note that this only works if a unix mail system is configured (there must be at least a `sendmail` command configured to talk to a local or remote MTA). This can generally be assumed to be the case on servers with competent administrators. On desktop machines, email is typically configured by the user in each email client.

Comment: Didn't realize `mail` was non-standard, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @fkraiem It was included in SUSv2 as legacy and removed from SUSv3. The `mail` command exists just about everywhere in practice, but its options (even to specify the subject) are even less portable than `mailx`'s.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that the machine has its sendmail configured properly, you can use simply

`mailx -s Subject recipent@somewhere.org < myemail.txt`

It is both more and less portable than the other answer. On the one hand, sendmail has to be configured on the machine. On the other hand, if it *is* configured, then the proper settings will be used, instead of some arbitrary ones.

**EDIT:** changed `mail` to [the standard `mailx`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/mailx.html).